# Not able to run AngularJS timer example

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

When i try to run the below example mentioned in the Angular JS timer site, I am getting error:

```
ng:areq
Bad Argument
Argument 'MyAppController' is not a function, got undefined

http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/ng/areq?p0=MyAppController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)
    at file:///C:/ICDP/Angular/angular/angular.min.js:6:417
    at Sb (file:///C:/ICDP/Angular/angular/angular.min.js:19:510)
    at tb (file:///C:/ICDP/Angular/angular/angular.min.js:20:78)
    at file:///C:/ICDP/Angular/angular/angular.min.js:75:331
    at file:///C:/ICDP/Angular/angular/angular.min.js:57:65
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AngularJS Example - Multiple Timers Example</title>
    <script src="../angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../app/js/timer.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module('MyApp', ['timer']);
        function MyAppController($scope) {
            $scope.timerRunning = true;

            $scope.startTimer = function (){
                $scope.$broadcast('timer-start');
                $scope.timerRunning = true;
            };

            $scope.stopTimer = function (){
                $scope.$broadcast('timer-stop');
                $scope.timerRunning = false;
            };
        }
        MyAppController.$inject = ['$scope'];
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyAppController">
        <h2>AngularJS - Multiple Timers Example</h2>
        <h3>Timer 1: <timer/></h3>
        <h3>Timer 2: <timer interval="2000"/></h3>
        <h3>Timer 3: <timer> minutes,  seconds.</timer></h3>
        <button ng-click="startTimer()" ng-disabled="timerRunning">Start Timers</button>
        <button ng-click="stopTimer()" ng-disabled="!timerRunning">Stop Timers</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have the below two files included

```
  <script src="../angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../app/js/timer.js"></script>
```

http://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/examples.html#/plain-javascript-source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Chrome developer tools(F12), then open folder with file: angular-timer -> examples -> angularjs-single-timer.html and you will see that (it is just little mistake):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AngularJS Example - Single Timer Example</title>

    <!-- compiled JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/assets/js/angular-timer-bower.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/assets/js/angular-timer-all.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module('MyApp', ['timer'])
        .controller('MyAppController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.timerRunning = true;

            $scope.startTimer = function (){
                $scope.$broadcast('timer-start');
                $scope.timerRunning = true;
            };

            $scope.stopTimer = function (){
                $scope.$broadcast('timer-stop');
                $scope.timerRunning = false;
            };

            $scope.$on('timer-stopped', function (event, data){
                console.log('Timer Stopped - data = ', data);
            });
        }]);
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyAppController">
        <h1>AngularJS - Single Timer Example</h1>
        <h3><timer/></h3>
        <button ng-click="startTimer()" ng-disabled="timerRunning">Start Timer</button>
        <button ng-click="stopTimer()" ng-disabled="!timerRunning">Stop Timer</button>
    </div>
    <br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks.. ICDApp.controller('maintenanceController',['$scope', '$filter', '$http', function($scope, $filter, $http).. How do i add [filter] to this one if i want to use an existing controler.

Comment: What is [filter]? Is it your custom module? If it is, just add row like that:  `var ICDApp = angular.module('ICDApp', ['filter']);` Then you can use, for example services that defined at 'filter' module, inside your controllers the same way as '$scope', '$http' etc.

Comment: Sorry i meant TImer.. Even though i add timer angular.module('ICDApp', ['filter']); the time is not getting displayed .. conole.log inside startTimer and stopTimer  are getting printed when i click button but timer doesnt showup.

Comment: I recommend you to create plunker or jsfiddle sample of you app for clear understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You have not MyAppController **Controller**. You must tell  angular that there is  controller named MyAppController. Try this to fix your problem.

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['timer']).controller('MyAppController', MyAppController);
```

And link  that can be useful  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller